# Set a dropdown option to selected based on get variable in url in Razor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdown menu in a GET form. When the user hits submit, they are directed to the same page and shown the form again. I would like to have the dropdown option the user displayed in the last page already selected. So for example:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Type", null, "Type", new { @class = "sbox-input" } )
```

website.com/Search?Type="Beef"

```
<select name="Type">
   <option value="Fish" >Fish</option>
   <option value="Chicken" >Chicken</option>
   <option value="Beef" selected="selected">Beef</option>
</select>
```

A jQuery solution would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need javascript to do this as long as you have `type` parameter in you Action. I assume that you have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Search(string type, [other parameters])
{
    ....
    ViewBag.SearchType = type; // put the selected type to the ViewBag
}
```

[SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) takes `selectedValue` as fourth parameter to it's constructor, so you can easy create `DropDownList` in the View with the selected value:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Type", new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Fish", "Fish" }, { "Chicken", "Chicken" }, { "Beef", "Beef" } }, "Key", "Value", ViewBag.SearchType))
```

Of course you can create the `SelectList` in the Action and pass it to the View:

```
public ActionResult Search(string type, [other parameters])
{
    ....
    ViewBag.SearchTypeList = new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Fish", "Fish" }, { "Chicken", "Chicken" }, { "Beef", "Beef" } }, "Key", "Value", type); // you can assign this to the property of your ViewModel if you have one
}
```

and then in the View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Type", ViewBag.SearchTypeList)
```